# Making axes line up

Tags: pgfplots

I'm working on the following graphic:

[image: Problematic graphic]

I would like the y axis of the plot in the upper right corner to line up exactly (i.e. have the ticks line up) with the x axis of the rotated plot to its left. I'd also like to get rid of the extra "0" that seems to be present in the left plot. 
The code is as follows:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
 \pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{2}{%
  \pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}%
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 1, remember picture]
  \begin{axis}[axis line style = thick, smooth, no markers,
    axis lines = left, axis line style={->}, xmin = 0, xmax = 4, name
    = main plot]
   \addplot[samples = 200] gnuplot{norm((x-2)/0.75)};
   \coordinate (A) at (axis cs:1.75, 0.3694413);
   \coordinate (C) at (axis cs:2.25, 0.6305587);
   \draw[dashed] (A) -- (0, 0.3694413);
   \draw[dashed] (C) -- (0, 0.6305587);
   \draw[thick, blue, <->] (0.1, 0.38) -- (0.1, 0.62);
  \end{axis}
   \begin{axis}[at={(main plot.below south west)}, yshift=-0.3cm,
     anchor = north west, axis line style = thick, smooth, no markers,
    axis lines = left, axis line style={->}, xmin = 0, xmax = 4, y = 6cm/3, ymin = 0, ymax = 1.0]
    \addplot[samples = 400] {gauss(2, 0.75^2)};
    \coordinate (B) at (axis cs:1.75,0);
    \coordinate (D) at (axis cs:2.25,0);
    \draw[thick, blue, <->] (1.76, 0.1) -- (2.24, 0.1);
   \end{axis}
   \draw[dashed] (A) -- (B);
   \draw[dashed] (C) -- (D);
    \begin{axis}[xshift = -3cm, axis line style = thick, smooth, no
      markers, y = 6cm/3, y tick label style={rotate=45,
        anchor=north east, inner sep=0mm}, 
    axis lines = left, axis line style={->}, xmin = 0, xmax = 1, ymin = 0, ymax = 1, 
   rotate around={90:(0,0)}
    ]
    \addplot[blue, thick] {1};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Check out group plots in the manual.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the `height` of the top right plot to the same explicit value as the `width` of the top left plot. To scale all axes the same, set the height of the bottom axis to the same value. As I understand it, the ticks on the two adjacent axes are identical, so you can remove the ticklabels from the x-axis on the top left plot. This will also remove that extra zero you mention.

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
 \pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{2}{%
  \pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}%
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 1, remember picture]

  \begin{axis}[axis line style = thick, smooth, no markers,
    axis lines = left, axis line style={->}, xmin = 0, xmax = 4, name
    = main plot,
    height=6cm]
   \addplot[samples = 200] gnuplot{norm((x-2)/0.75)};
   \coordinate (A) at (axis cs:1.75, 0.3694413);
   \coordinate (C) at (axis cs:2.25, 0.6305587);
   \draw[dashed] (A) -- (0, 0.3694413);
   \draw[dashed] (C) -- (0, 0.6305587);
   \draw[thick, blue, <->] (0.1, 0.38) -- (0.1, 0.62);
  \end{axis}

   \begin{axis}[at={(main plot.below south west)}, yshift=-0.3cm,
     anchor = north west, axis line style = thick, smooth, no markers,
    axis lines = left, axis line style={->}, xmin = 0, xmax = 4, y = 6cm/3, ymin = 0, ymax = 1.0,
    height=6cm]
    \addplot[samples = 400] {gauss(2, 0.75^2)};
    \coordinate (B) at (axis cs:1.75,0);
    \coordinate (D) at (axis cs:2.25,0);
    \draw[thick, blue, <->] (1.76, 0.1) -- (2.24, 0.1);
   \end{axis}

   \draw[dashed] (A) -- (B);
   \draw[dashed] (C) -- (D);

    \begin{axis}[xshift = -3cm, axis line style = thick, smooth, no
      markers, y = 6cm/3, y tick label style={rotate=45,
        anchor=north east, inner sep=0mm},
    axis lines = left, axis line style={->}, xmin = 0, xmax = 1, ymin = 0, ymax = 1, 
    rotate around={90:(0,0)},
    width=6cm,xticklabels={},xtick={0,0.2,...,0.8}
    ]
    \addplot[blue, thick] {1};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```